# How can I trap an error when Access starts up, before the first form is loaded?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database with linked back end tables that I relink at runtime, depending on user input. My problem is that at startup they have the wrong link and I get an error message. I just want to stop the error message coming up. It happens as soon as Access starts, before any form is loaded, so trapping it in the form load event is too late! Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you remove the table links before closing the DB?

Comment: I have not tried to remove the table links. Do you mean to change a table's link to be just a null string? Or should I somehow change the table to not be a linked table any more, and then later create the link when I reopen the DB at the stage when I know the target back end I want it to link to? Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If making them a nullstring circumvents the error message, then yes, otherwise removing the entire link and recreating it upon opening the DB as soon as you know where to link to. I haven’t worked that much with Access myself, though, so just a suggestion :)

Comment: Hit Alt+F11 to see the code and hit F9 right after the form load event.  Finally, hit F8 to step through the code one line at a time.

Comment: The "error" comes during the form load event because the link to the back end table is wrong. It seems a nullstring connection is illegal. I can't see how to "unlink" a table using code. Also, if the form has no table, I guess it will not be happy trying to deal with the data-related controls on the form. Asher, hitting F9 is too late, the error happened as pat of the form load, but not in my VBA code for that event. Finally, I can't even test the form's connection to see if it needs changing, because that would mean having to load the form first!

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions, folks, but I now have a simple solution. My problem was accessing Access back end tables from various different laptops, via Dropbox. If one laptop had been connected, and links made, then a second one would get an immediate error because the link would be wrong.The link requires an absolute path, not a relative one. I found that if each laptop had a logged-in user with the same name the paths would identical on each laptop, eg C:\Users\just me\Dropbox\backend.accdb. So no relinking necessary!